# Play framework- design suggestion for validation

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to validate if a certain newly added entity, part of my model has already been added. The addition would happen by taking input from a user. 
I believe the standard way to do it is to add constraints in the form along the lines of

```
.verifying( "Already exists", <code to check if entity already exists> )
```

This would lead to a globalError is the entity already exists. The error message would be a static "Already exists". 
What I'm looking for, though, is to also tell the user what possible matches exist, something the globalError would be incapable of doing.

Should I do what I want to do by not adding the validator and by allowing the binding to succeed? This way, when I do a

```
myForm.fold{ Entity returned as success => <success code>, erroneousForm =>  <failure code>}
```

I can take the success branch and then check there if the entity could be duplicate? If similarities exist then I can redirect the user? I feel like this shouldn't be the controller's job, and this is too much of design logic inside controller, this should technically all lie inside the model itself. And the model should only tell the controller that something is wrong and the 'type of w can first create the new element and then upon finding that potential rongness' and the controller can take appropriate action. It shouldn't have to contain code to determine if there is anything wrong.

Can someone please suggest what should be a good way to do it?

Comment: You are mixing different concerns and it is not possible to give you a concise answer to your question. You probably would wanna split in two or three questions. How do I perform dynamic validation on a form? Where is the right place to perform model validation? Etc etc

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Thank you for taking the time to read the question and leaving comment. I guess what I'm thinking is that precise situations get precise answers, and I will get very general answers for 'how to perform validation on a form', or 'what is the right place'. I'm looking to get the best practices in this specific situation because this is what I'm facing right now. 
Although answers to parts of the problem, if the answerer thinks would help the community, are welcome too.